Prevent module name from being minified in webpack bundle
I have a host application that consumes a remote package through a script tag.
My remote package includes the following ModuleFederationPlugin config within the webpack config
plugins: [
  new webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'myWonderfulModule',
    filename: '[name].js',
    exposes: {
      '.': './src/index.js', 
    },
  }),
],

Typically this results in a file that starts with the following
var myWonderfulModule;
/******/ var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ 986:
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports, __webpack_require__) => {

And I am able to import this module dynamically in the host app using dynamic import
import('myWonderfulModule')...

However, when the remote is minified, it loses the var name at the top of the bundled file (var myWonderfulModule ends up looking like var r or something similar).
I believe this is why I see an myWonderfulModule is not found error when the assets have been minified.
I thought the terser-webpack-plugin might help resolve this issue so I added the following to my remote's webpack config
optimization: {
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        mangle: {
          properties: {
            reserved: ['myWonderfulModule'],
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
},

But still, var myWonderulModule is getting minified to var r.
Perhaps this is because myWonderfulModule isn't actually part of my code as much as it's just a name assigned to the module in webpack's ModuleFederationPlugin config.
So what can I do to preserve that name and still minify the remote bundle...?
Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem...?
(maybe my assumptions are incorrect?)

What is the webpack entry name (object key) for the remote build? Does it match the name used in the federation plugin?

@morganney are you wondering what value is assigned to the entry property in the webpack config?  If so it looks like this entry: path.join(dirName, '/src/index')

Ok. You might want to try using object form and having the names match. For example, entry: { myWonderfulModule: path.join(dirName, '/src/index') }. Not sure this will work, but worth a try. I saw a note about that here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/

I think the minification of the var myWonderulModule might be a red haring. Is the built code available or event better the source repo?

Thanks for the suggestion @morganney.  I tried modifying the entry point as you suggested, but still seeing myWonderfulModule var getting minified to r.

@Geo52rey unfortunately it's all proprietary / private.  not able to share actual code.

Update on suggestion from @morganney.  Upon further inspection, that change does actually preserve myWonderfulModule in many places that were minified by webpack, just not in the areas generated by webpack.  Maybe that's enough.  I'll experiment further.

Following up on my last comment.  Adding a named entry point did not resolve the issue I'm having.
